# How can I check if a function remains unevaluated?

Tags: evaluation, hold

I am trying to check if a function remains unevaluated.

For example

$$\int \ln ^5(3 x) \sec (3 x) \, dx$$

remains unevaluated in Mathematica, instead 
$$\int \sec (3 x) \, dx$$
doesn't.

What I tried is

```
func = Log[3 x]^5*Sec[3 x];
IntFunc = With[{function = func}, HoldForm[Integrate[function, x]]];
SameQ[IntFunc,ReleaseHold[IntFunc]]
```

which returns `False`. I also tried

```
Equal[IntFunc,ReleaseHold[IntFunc]]
```

which remains unevaluated. I am pretty sure that this has to do with `Hold` $(*)$ but I don't understand how to fix this. Is there a way to test if a function remains unevaluatd? In other words, get `True` if it's unevaluated and `False` if it's evaluated?

---

$(*)$ Because when I try:

```
SameQ[Integrate[func, x], ReleaseHold[IntFunc]]
```

it returns `True`.

Comment: `ValueQ` should do the trick.

Comment: @JEM_Mosig how?

Comment: From the documentation: `ValueQ[expr]` gives `True` if a value has been defined for `expr`, and gives `False` otherwise. `ValueQ` gives `False` only if `expr` would not change if it were to be entered as Wolfram Language input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> check if a function remains unevaluated.

Why not just check the head?

```
func = Log[3 x]^5*Sec[3 x];
result = Integrate[func, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
If[Head[result] === Integrate,
 Print["Opps"],
 Print["it worked"]
 ]
```

**Update for comment**

Use this to check if result contains `Integrate` anywhere

```
func = 20* Log[3 x]^5*Sec[3 x];
result = Integrate[func, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
If[FreeQ[result, Integrate, Infinity],
 Print["it worked"],
 Print["Opps"]
 ]
```

Comment: Wow, I did not think of this! Thanks! '

Comment: Hey, I just noticed that this does **not** work if a constant is added in front of the function (ex: `func = 20*Log[3 x]^5*Sec[3 x];`). This because the head now is `Times`. How would you fix this?

Comment: @DMH16 I added check

Answer (score 2):

`ValueQ` should do exactly what you want.
From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ.html): `ValueQ[expr]` gives `True` if a value has been defined for `expr`, and gives `False` otherwise. `ValueQ` gives `False` only if `expr` would not change if it were to be entered as Wolfram Language input.

So

```
ValueQ[Integrate[Log[3 x]^5*Sec[3 x], x]]
(* False *)
```

and

```
ValueQ[Integrate[Sec[3 x], x]]
(* True *)
```